# lyx longtable with one LoT entry and a header on every page

Tags: lyx, longtable

I have a longtable which is spread over several pages. If I make the top row a header it appears once in the list of tables BUT I want it to appear on each page of the table... If I make the top row a header it makes several entries in the list of tables. Ideas?

Edit: Apparently this is fixable in latex but I am hoping to do it in LyX. Unfortunately, my thesis guidlines require the header appear on each page.

Edit: Thanks to commenters jon and scottkosty! the solution is to select both header and 'first header' in the longtable tab page on the table settings.

Comment: I've never used Lyx, but with `longtable`, you need to make the appropriate use of `\endhead` and (in some cases) `\endfirsthead`.  The basic structure is: `\begin{longtable}{<table specs>} <header line(s)> \endhead <table body> \end{longtable}`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'd like to try to do it all in LyX as to not break anything.

Comment: I suppose you mean LyX hides that code from the user..? Can't help with that -- though maybe you can look for some kind of help menu that talks about `\endhead`: LyX *must* use it if it uses the `longtable` package.

Comment: Did you look in the longtable settings? Go to the table settings, click on "Longtable", then click on "on" for the Header. Do that in the row that you want to be the header. Does that work?

Comment: Yes, it does make the header appear on each page as I want, but it also adds an entry to the list of tables for each of those pages.

Comment: there should be a setting just for the first heading (but I don't know lyx)

Comment: @AnotherThesis yes there is a "first header" check box in LyX.

Comment: @PaulGessler thanks. I don't know of a duplicate for LyX so I answered.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the row of that you want to be the header. Go to "More", then "Settings". Then click on the "Longtable" tab, select "Use long table". Then click on "First header".